# Excel VBA - Write Formula referencing cell values

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-formula

I am trying to enter a formula in a cell referencing cells which will be filled manually.
For example, `A3` references `A1` and `A2`, but those two values will be filled by me.

In this case, `cell [dateColumnCounter][r] = [dateColumnCounter][r+!] - [dateColumnCounter][r+2]`

I can't use direct cell names unfortunately because those will change based on the counter values.

This is what I thought would work, but doesn't:

```
Worksheets("Hours").Cells(r, dateColumnCounter).Formula = "=" & 
Worksheets("Hours").Cells(r+1, dateColumnCounter).Value & "-" & 
Worksheets("Hours").Cells(r+2, dateColumnCounter).Value
```

Comment: "Would work, but isn't" What error pops?

Answer (score 1):

Try to do something equivalent as:

```
Sub Sum()

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Cells(3, 1).Formula = "=SUM(" & .Cells(1, 1).Value & "+" & .Cells(2, 1).Value & ")"
    End With

End Sub
```

This particular code worked for me.
Pay attention to the Sheet name and the cells you need to use.

I know you need to turn the Row and Column numbers into iterable indexes, but that's easy from here.